# Extra space above prototype cell. Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

If you look at the screenshot below of my table view theres a big gap between the prototype cell and the top of the table. Ive tried to re-size it but it just resizes the whole thing. Does anyone know how to make the prototype cell closer to the top of the table view?

[image]

Comment: You problem is solved by that answer? It seems to me that you just need to fix the table view constraints instead of putting in a view.

Comment: it did seem to work but not sure if thats the best way to do it. How would you solve it?

Comment: In attributes builder of your view controller, uncheck Adjust Scrollview Insets. Then set padding of your tableview to be 0 on all four directing with the view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some sort of a bug, but it is easily solved.  Drag a UIView from the object library and add it above the TableView as I've done in the image below.  The problem should resolve itself.

[image: TableView gap]